# Naming log folder

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone;
Is there any way to specify in my python program the name of the folder to which logs for respective nodes are saved?

As in, when I launch my experiment via `roslaunch`, I'll see something like the following text:

```
... logging to /home/user/catkin_ws/src/project/logs/51342e8a-7f6c-11e8-a056-5404a63cee0d/roslaunch-user-desktop-22693.log
```

My question is whether I can programatically set the name of the folder `51342e8a-7f6c-11e8-a056-5404a63cee0d` each time I run the experiment?
Ideally the folder name would be the exact date/time the experiment was launched..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296209/naming-log-folder/) by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `51342e8a-7f6c-11e8-a056-5404a63cee0d` string is actually a parameter called run_id (you get check it by calling `rosparam get /run_id`) that is generated uniquely while starting roscore. This parameter should not be changed. What you can change is the path before that (`/home/user/catkin_ws/src/project/logs/` in your example) by setting the `$ROS_LOG_DIR` environment variable.
One solution that could work for you is to set this environment variable to the current time programmatically using a script before every launch. Then while collecting these logs you can write a simple script that goes inside each log folder and moves the content one directory level up.

---

Originally posted by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) with karma: 161 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) on 2018-07-04**:
That sounds like it will work. Seems a shame that there isn't a more elegant (in-built) solution as it's quite an obvious feature.. Anyway, thanks for your help!